# slick can i use mapped projection for updates?

Tags: slick

To use db side autoinc id most things suggest to use a custom (forInsert) projection without the id, now i want to use the same projection for updating, but i can't figure out how (or if it is possible)

```
class Users extends Table[User]("user") {
   def id = column[UserId]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
   def email = column[String]("email")
   def password = column[String]("password")

   def * = id.? ~ email ~ password <>(User, User.unapply _)

   def forInsert = email ~ password <>( {
     (email, password) => User(None, email, password)
   }, {
     u: User => Some((u.email, u.password))
   })

   def uniqueEmail = index("idx_email", email, unique = true)
 }
```

This allows you do to do

```
Users.forInsert.insert(User(None, "foo", "bar"))
```

Now given an id and a User can i update a row without having to set the id in the User ?

Query(Users).filter(_.id == id).magic(Users.forInsert).update(User(None, "foo", "bar"))

Comment: I didn't find any example in official document about using mapped projection for updates..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse the insert projection, but you can easily define an update projection and execute.

Users.filter(_.id === id).map(p => p.email ~ p.password).update(email, password)